# No matching function for call (expects reference to pointer instead of pointer)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc

I get the error from xcode (3.2.4)/gcc(4.0):

```
/Users/admin/scm/audacity/mac/../src/toolbars/DeviceToolBar.cpp: In member function 'void DeviceToolBar::ShowInputDialog()':
/Users/admin/scm/audacity/mac/../src/toolbars/DeviceToolBar.cpp:817: error: no matching function for call to 'DeviceToolBar::ShowComboDialog(wxChoice*&, wxString)'
/Users/admin/scm/audacity/mac/../src/toolbars/DeviceToolBar.h:74: note: candidates are: void DeviceToolBar::ShowComboDialog(wxChoice*, wxString&)
```

So it looks like it expects a reference to a pointer in ShowComboDialog, but I don't know why as the signatures are clearly normal pointers.  Furthermore if it was expecting a reference to a pointer the way I am calling it should work.
This is the first error, and there are no special warnings before it.

Also, this compiles in MSVC 2008 express.
Please give me a clue.

```
//in the class def
//(only relevant portions included
class DeviceToolBar:public ToolBar {

 public:
   DeviceToolBar();
   virtual ~DeviceToolBar();
   void ShowInputDialog();
 private:
   void ShowComboDialog(wxChoice *combo, wxString &title);

   wxChoice *mInput;
};

//in the cpp file
void DeviceToolBar::ShowInputDialog()
{
   ShowComboDialog(mInput, wxString(_("Select Input Device")));
}

void DeviceToolBar::ShowComboDialog(wxChoice *combo, wxString &title)
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not the first parameter; its the second.  You're passing in a temporary `wxString`, but the function is expecting a reference.  C++ will automatically convert a temporary to a `const` reference, but it cannot convert it to a reference.  You need to make `ShowComboDialog` take a const reference as its second parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Your `ShowComboDialog` takes a `wxString` by non-const reference and you are trying to pass a temporary object as an argument to this parameter.  You can only bind const references to temporary objects.

You either need to change `ShowComboDialog` to take its second argument either by value (`wxString`) or by const reference (`const wxString&`) or you need to create a variable for the `wxString` that you create when you call the function and then pass (a reference to) that variable instead.